JBoss EAP - Upgrade from 7.4.2 to 7.4.3
We are looking to upgrade JBoss EAP(JBoss Enterprise Application Platform) 7.4.2 to 7.4.3.
Currently, Application is running in
java-11-openjdk-11.0.10-1 
jboss-eap-7.4.2.
java version "1.8.0_301

I want to know if there is any pre-requisite, before making the upgrading.
Does all jars supported in 7.4.2 supported in 7.4.3?
Do i have to upgrade Java also for this?

What does the documentation say?
